# Boosting in Solr based on date with conditions

Tags: lucene, solr, nutch

I am trying to boost newer documents in Solr queries. The ms function [Solr FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) seems to be the right way to go, but I need to add an additional condition:
I am using the last-Modified-Date from crawled web pages as the date to consider, and that does not always provide a meaningful date. Therefore I would like the function to only boost documents where the date (not time) found in the last-Modified-Date is different from the timestamp, eliminating results that just return the current date as the last-Modified-Date. Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I appreciate the answers provided so far, but they do not address my question:  I would like the function to only boost documents where the date (not time) found in the last-Modified-Date is different from the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do want to do it in the business layer, as baja fresh suggested. However, there is a pure Solr way to do it: just use the [map](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#map) function to map anything in the range `(timestamp,timestamp)` to `now`.

Answer (score 0):

During indexing, apply your logic and add the date to a "date_boost" field.  During search time, boost using the date_boost field.